# Monte Carlo for estimating small

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, monte-carlo, simulation

Suppose that I have two samples $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and $y_1,\cdots, y_m$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, with $m$ and $n$ very large. I want to estimate the probability $P(Y>X)$ which I know is small, something like $0.0001456$. If I use traditional montecarlo taking $N$ pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ and counting how many of them satisfy $y_i>x_i$ to estimate this probability I would need many simulations to aproximate it accurately, with enough decimal places. I would like to know if there are better monte carlo methods to estimate this probability with less simulations than this approach, maybe using aditional information from somewhere.

Comment: Without a little more detail I can't really suggest much, but if you know a little bit more than what you have said here then you may be able to implement importance sampling for a problem like this. An example where this would be possible would be if $X$ is supported on $[a,b]$ and $Y$ is supported on $[c,d]$ where $a<c<d<b$. Then you could generate samples where $X$ is always forced to be in $[a,d]$ and renormalize by $P(X \in [a,d])$ at the end to finish.

Comment: (Cont.) Ultimately the goal of importance sampling is to reduce the ratio of the standard deviation of the estimator to the mean of the estimator while keeping the mean of the estimator the same.

Comment: Some further clarification:
1) What do you know about the distributions of $X$ and $Y$? I guess there must be more since you know that the probability $Y>X$ is small.
2) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Aside from importance sampling which has rightfully been suggested by @Ian, you may want to have a look at "FORM/SORM" algorithms, which are very commonly used in engineering to estimate probability of failures (often very small), modeled as $\mathbb P(g(\mathbf X) <0) $ (in your case that would be $\mathbb P(X-Y <0)$). Unfortunately I don't know any good introductory material in English, but you can first try running Google translate on the [French wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_FORM-SORM) to get an idea of what it is about.

Comment: Try asking your question in [stats.se].

Comment: Let $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=4,\sigma=1)$ and $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ Then you can use @StratosFair's method to evaluate $P(Y > X).$ The following simulation in R provides small absolute error, but moderately large relative error. So this version of the problem is hardly ideal for approximation by simulation. R-code: `set.seed(2021);  x = rnorm(10^6, 4,1); y = rnorm(10^6, 0,1); mean(y > x)` returns 
$ 0.002361.$ An exact solution in terms of $X - Y$ is $0.002338867.$

Comment: Isn't it traditional montecarlo with the pairs x,y given by their initial order? @BruceET

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'traditional Monte Carlo' or by 'initial order'. Just attempted to show R code for what I took to be your method. In R, `y > x` is a logical vector of $10^6$ T's and F's and its `mean` is the proportion of its T's. // There is almost always a 'better method' by some criterion: speed of running, length of program, use of memory, etc. This is a simple job and your method seems fine. (My code is short, uses about $3\times 10^6$ positions in memory, Runs almost instantaneously.) But I don't know what level of sophistication is expected of you for this assignment.

Comment: In R `mean(replicate(10^6, rnorm(1,-4,1)>rnorm(1)))` temporarily uses about 1/3 the memory and takes a few seconds longer to run (noticeable). Gives essentially same answer.